# How to avoid implicit 'null' substitution in GraphQL (AWS App Sync)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, velocity, aws-appsync

Consider below query:

```js
const fetchItemsQuery = `query(
  $paginationPageSize: Int! 
  $paginationPageNumber: Int!
  $searchByNameRequest: String
  $categoryID: String
) {
  getItems(
    paginationPageSize: $paginationPageSize
    paginationPageNumber: $paginationPageNumber
    searchByNameRequest: $searchByNameRequest
    categoryID: $categoryID
  ) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

If to submit it from client side with variables:

```
{
  paginationPageSize: 20,
  paginationPageNumber: 1
}
```

in AWS App Sync logs, it reads:

```
{
  paginationPageSize: 20,
  paginationPageNumber: 1,
  searchByNameRequest: null,
  categoryID: null
}
```

I checked the request payload from browser - no nulls, just

```
{
  paginationPageSize: 20,
  paginationPageNumber: 1
}
```

So the cause is not in frontend side.

I found out that the `null` substitution occurring in **request resolving template**:

```
{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Invoke",
  "payload": {
    "field": "listProduct",
    "arguments": $util.toJson($context.args) // <- here
  }
}
```

`$util.toJson` uses Apache Velocity.

Can I avoid `$util.toJson($context.args)` will substitute the nulls in my request variables?

**Important:** the solution should not touch the *explicitly* submitted nulls .

Comment: did you end up resolving this? It seems pretty bad of appsync to not think that null has meaning in GraphQL compared to undefined or non-present. The defaults option below seems like a hacky workaround

Answer (score 1):

You could try to filter out null arguments from the `$context.args` map.

```
#set( $args = {} )
#foreach( $entry in $context.args.entrySet())
  #if( $entry.value != $null )
    #set( $junk = $args.put($entry.key, $entry.value) )
  #end
#end

{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Invoke",
  "payload": {
    "field": "listProduct",
    "arguments": $util.toJson($args)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But what if null has been submitted explicitly?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu You could assign default values like ` = "__DEFAULT__"` to GraphQL arguments, and check for this value to spot unspecified arguments.